# Show/Hide when input radio is checked

Tags: input, show-hide, prestashop-1.7

I need to show a div **only** if an input is checked.
So I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#group_1 input').each(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == ('23') && $(this).is(':checked')) {
          $('#showtext').show();

  } else {
      $('#showtext').hide();
  }
 });
 });
```

The group called is here (PrestaShop 1.7.5.1):

```
 {elseif $group.group_type == 'radio'}
<ul id="group_{$id_attribute_group}">
  {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
    <li class="input-container float-xs-left">
      <label class="accordion--form__label">
        <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="{$id_attribute_group}" name="group[{$id_attribute_group}]" value="{$id_attribute}"{if $group_attribute.selected} checked="checked"{/if}>
        <span class="radio-label">{$group_attribute.name}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  {/foreach}
</ul>
 {/if}
```

BUT, I need that if #group_1 value 24 is checked or nothing is checked >  hide #showtext. 
I can't have this. What's wrong?

The source code for the value 23 that I want to hide/show is:

```
<input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="1" name="group[1]" value="23" checked="checked">
```

When this is active, div must be hidden:

```
<input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="1" name="group[1]" value="24">
```

Comment: I still can't find a solution to this problem. Anybody can?

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons don't have id called "group_1", but they have name called "group[1]". In this case you can use jquery to access by name like this.

```
         <div class="container">

                23 <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="1" name="group[1]" value="23" checked > 

                24 <input class="input-radio" type="radio" data-product-attribute="1" name="group[1]" value="24">

                <div id="showtext">This is what is to be shown or hidden</div>
            </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {   
                var radioValue = $("input[name='group[1]']:checked").val();
                //alert(radioValue);
                if(radioValue == '23') {
                    $('#showtext').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#showtext').hide();
                }


                $("input[type='radio'][name='group[1]']").click(function() {
                    radioValue = $("input[name='group[1]']:checked").val();
                    //alert(radioValue);
                    if(radioValue == '23') {
                        $('#showtext').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#showtext').hide();
                    }                        
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks! It works for the first step, but if I check radio 23 and then the second radio 24 the text isn't hidden. 
I mean: 
click on first radio > show text works! (thanks!)
after this, if I want to change and I click on the second radio > show text isn't hidden :(

Comment: And I have to add that, if I check again the first radio the div doesn't show this time....

Comment: I am sorry.. but I could not reproduce the error that you mention.  I left the 23 radio button initially unchecked and even then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem now it's that: if I check the input 24 and then I click the input 23 (the div is now visible) to choose again the input 24, the div doesn't hide.
The code works well if I take it singulary, but in the PrestaShop product.tpl, I have this problem. The "showtext" stays visible.
Do you have ideas about what error could be? Maybe the form cart?

The input are inside the form, the div outside (because it has another form inside product-customization.tpl):

```
 <form action="{$urls.pages.cart}" method="post" id="add-to-cart-or-refresh">
              <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$product.id}" id="product_page_product_id">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_customization" value="{$product.id_customization}" id="product_customization_id">
```